# How can I implement scheduled push notifications for Android and IOS App on my parse server?

Tags: android, node.js, parse-platform, push-notification, parse-server

Parse-push-notifications have certain cons including -

1. No job queue system.
2. Scheduled push is not supported.

And so I am thinking to use a different pushadapter.

I have two questions -

1. Does my approach seems correct?
2. If yes, which npm package/ push adapter can I use?
3. What will be the configuration of using this third-party push adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Using third-party push adapters is a valid approach. They are provided by companies like

[OneSignal](http://www.onesignal.com) ([Website](http://www.onesignal.com) | [Adapter Github link](https://github.com/inoutput/parse-server-onesignal-push-adapter))

[Pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com) ([Website](https://www.pushwoosh.com) | [Adapter Github link](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-parse-adapter))

The caveat is that it might cost money, or that they are selling the push data to advertisers. Which, in the case of OneSignal, is explicitly stated in their [help section under "FREE"](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs#section-why-should-i-use-onesignal).

In that case you need to replace the standard adapter (which has paths to the APNS p12 certificates and credentials to FCM) with another configuration that includes your API keys to the third party provider. This is described in the readme of the adapter repositories.
Then you need to configure their service with the APNS certificates and FCM credentials.

Alternatively, you can use *your own scheduler*, but that seems a bit more involved. I've read a good article about it here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-get-parse-background-job-functionality-server-andrey-gordeev/
and the Parse Team recommends using **kue** for the job (https://github.com/Automattic/kue).

There are some efforts in the Parse Open Source community to build an adapter that supports push notification scheduling. Check out this issue for the latest news (November 2017):
https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/4105

Comment: Hey thanks! So for me simple way would be using third party.. and I m thinking to use OneSignal. Any idea of the proper docs for this stuff? @Julian

Comment: You really don't care about your customers' data? Well, ok. OneSignal has some documentation here: https://onesignal.com/parse